# What to choose for article management website

Tags: java, php, article

I have some questions regarding article management system.
I am thinking of making a website where people will become members and write their articles, they can publish them, rank them etc. 
And i have been googling for past two weeks that which technology is best. 
And how to store the article so that search engines (like google, yahoo, etc.) can find those articles.
If the articles are stored as html somewhere on my server then Google Spider programs will be able to get them for search results 
but if i store the content of my article in MySQL (the database which i want to use), how would search engines rank my website articles. 
I am really confused, please guide me. 
I need to know if there is any PHP article management script which is open source which i can update or change to suit my needs and
has not been hacked. Or Java Content management script or something which can save me the time to develop this whole thing.
I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Sounds like any decent blog software could work for you.

Answer (score 2):

Generally if you store the content in a database, you have scripts which serve up that content, and thus search engine spiders index the served versions of the article.

There are many content management systems out there, it's really a subjective choice which one you choose. Whether or not something "has been hacked" is a poor indicator of whether it can currently and/or might in the future be compromised; the developers of CMS software tend to patch known holes and it's impossible to predict future holes based on past ones, so really, you're best bet is to just try to find something with solid support and active development, and patch frequently as security updates are released.

Comment: So if my application is in Java and I have a form where user enters article heading and content , tags etc and all that information is stored in database, so how you mean each time user comes to my website and open that article and my application pulls this information from the database to show the article as an html page with dynamic content but this html doesn't exist so how search engines will rank the page. I am still confused. Can you give me an example how it will be implemented.

Comment: Search engines visit your website just like any other visitor. If visitors see HTML, search engines will see HTML too.

Answer (score 0):

> If the articles are stored as html somewhere on my server then Google Spider programs will be able to get them for search results but if i store the content of my article in MySQL (the database which i want to use), how would search engines rank my website articles.

It doesn't matter how they are stored, only that they are addressable via http URIs. Browsers don't access data in databases, they make requests to web servers (which might run programs to fetch data from databases or might fetch data from files on the file system).

> I need to know if there is any PHP article management script which is open source which i can update or change to suit my needs and has not been hacked. Or Java Content management script or something which can save me the time to develop this whole thing.

Hundreds, in both [Java](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=java%20cms) and [PHP](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=php%20cms).

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, storing article data in a database is no problem.  The articles will get rendered into HTML by some script, and displayed on your site, where search engines will find them.  There are a bunch of techniques to improve how well your articles will show up in search.

In this day and age, I wouldn't recommend rolling your own system.  There are a great number of off-the-shelf software packages that can handle your requirements.  [Wordpress](http://www.wordpress.org) is a very popular blogging system, written in PHP (with MySQL), that will probably meet all of your requirements.  It supports multiple authors (and various roles for authors such as author/editor/administrator), commenting/discussion, and has a huge array of [plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/) that provide additional or altered functionality.  It's well documented (both user and developer documentation), actively maintained, and pretty good overall.

If Wordpress doesn't float your boat, I'd look around at some of the other PHP-driven blogging tools.  There are a ton of them, and it's very likely that one will fit your needs, and you can avoid reinventing the wheel for the 900th time.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry i still didn't understand. Here is the example lets say user1 submitted the article1 and the content got stored in the database. Now on a home page there is a link "How to train your pet" and user clicks on this link and it goes to a servlet which pulls the article content and information from the database and generates an output and displays it into ... what an html or what like will it save the output as an html on the server so that next time when another user clicks on "How to train your pet" on the homepage he will be directed to this generated html
Or another case where servlet will generate the output on the browser where user will read and vote, rank etc. but in this case there is no html file so how would search engines will rank this article as this file doesn't exist. Its so confusing.

Comment: Please edit clarifications into your original question, since they're clearly not an 'answer' but a refinement of the question. Use the 'edit' link that should appear just below your question-text.